# Rails Bundle Update FetchError fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, bundle

Mac OSX 10.10.2
Ruby 2.2.0

I'm going through the "One Month Rails" course, and I'm stalling on the part where I need to add bootstrap to the project. I've tried tons of solutions recommended, but nothing seems to work for me.

Here is the error I keep getting:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out 
- connect(2) for "rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net" port 80     
(http://rubygems.org/gems/autoprefixer-rails-5.2.0.gem)

An error occurred while installing autoprefixer-rails
(5.2.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install autoprefixer-rails -v '5.2.0'`
succeeds before bundling.
```

Things that have failed:

1. Changing https to http does not work
2. Bundle update does not work
3. Restarting the computer does not work
4. Restarting the Terminal does not work

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install `autoprefixer-rails` gem using this command : `gem install autoprefixer-rails -v '5.2.0'` ? After that try `bundle install` again.

Comment: Thank you for your input! Unfortunately, it didn't work. this is what I got:                                                                                  `$ gem install autoprefixer-rails -v '5.2.0'
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'autoprefixer-rails' (= 5.2.0) in any repository`

Comment: Try to install without specifying version of Gemfile, `gem install autoprefixer-rails` and let me know.

Comment: Same result as before. It's probably unrelated, but I'm updating Xcode right now. We'll see if that helps. I also tried adding autoprefixer into the gem file like this: `gem 'autoprefixer-rails', '~>5.2.0'` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work, but I'm not sure what it was because.

It was one or more of the following:

1. I live in China, so I have to use a VPN for many things. I turned my VPN on. This probably wasn't it because the Rubygems website isn't blocked in China and I did try this before.
2. My XCode was out of date. I had to delete XCode and download it again to get the update.
3. I turned on root in the terminal with sudo su - before adding autoprefixer with `root# gem install autoprefixer-rails -v '5.2.0'`, as Rick suggested. I'm thinking the root install is what made this work. Yay!